# Disable Firebase crash reporting by using Firebase init

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics, firebase-crash-reporting

I've kept myself from using Firebase Analytics and Crash Reports because there was no way of disabling Crash Reporting.

I've seen the answers on other questions but not offered a proper way of doing it.

I've read an interesting thing on Firebase blog: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/03/take-control-of-your-firebase-init-on.html

I wonder, could this be used do disable analytics and crash reporting?
I mean, heaving something like:

```
if (user.wantsAnalytics()){
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this, builder.build());
}else{
 //do nothing and no analytics or crash reports will be sent.
}
```

If firebase isn't initialized, would push messaging still work?

Comment: There's currently no way to disable only Firebase Crash Reporting separately from other Firebase features.  That functionality is being worked on, so please stay tuned for future updates.

Comment: @DougStevenson thank you for your comment. Can you please confirm that by not doing initialize() the Firebase won't be loaded/used at all? From what I see, this would allow me to disable both Analytics and Crash Reporting in this way... if the user opts out.

Comment: You have to allow FirebaseApp to initialize in order to use any of the SDKs.  Normally this is called automatically for you by a ContentProvider that's added to your app.  https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/12/how-does-firebase-initialize-on-android.html